# Spring - Headers getting cleared in ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an exception handler in Spring. The goal is for this exception handler to just add some additional headers to the response.

If I set the status to 404 using response.setStatus, the headers get overwritten it seems like and I do not see the "something_random" header on the client side. It works fine if I omit the setStatus(404), but then the client gets a 200 with the header. Is there a way to ensure that the 404 response has the custom headers set?

**Spring version: 4.3.25**

What I've tried:

```
@ExceptionHandler(CustomNotFoundException.class)
public void handleFailure(Exception ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
  response.setHeader("something_random", "bob");
  reseponse.setStatus(404);
}
```

Also tried (not sure if different):

```
@ExceptionHandler(CustomNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleFailure(Exception ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
  // Initialize 'headers'
  return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the following with Spring Boot 2.4.2 (Spring Framework 5.3.3) and the `custom` header is present in the response:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidResponseException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleOpenApiResponseValidationExceptions(InvalidResponseException ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .header("custom", "value")
            .body(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Know this is old question but here is one way that can fit into this.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class ExceptionHandlingConfig {

@Autowired
private DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;

@PostConstruct
private void configureDispatcherServlet() {
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
 }

}
```